# using Kinect Depth View to show an Object inside the Human Body

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, hlsl, kinect-sdk

I currently working on Depth Data on Kinect SDK v1.8 on XNA and I wanna show an Image Inside the Depth view of Human body. the image below is just an example of what I wanna do :

http://static.gamespot.com/uploads/original/1535/15354745/2429785-screen4.jpg

for Depth View, this is what I've done :

```
void kinectSensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (DepthImageFrame depthImageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthImageFrame != null)
        {
            short[] pixelsFromFrame = new short[depthImageFrame.PixelDataLength];

            depthImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelsFromFrame);
            byte[] convertedPixels = ConvertDepthFrame(pixelsFromFrame, ((KinectSensor)sender).DepthStream, 640 * 480 * 4);

            Color[] color = new Color[depthImageFrame.Height * depthImageFrame.Width];
            kinectRGBVideo = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, depthImageFrame.Width, depthImageFrame.Height);

            // Set convertedPixels from the DepthImageFrame to a the datasource for our Texture2D
            kinectRGBVideo.SetData<byte>(convertedPixels);
        }
    }
}


// Converts a 16-bit grayscale depth frame which includes player indexes into a 32-bit frame
// that displays different players in different colors
private byte[] ConvertDepthFrame(short[] depthFrame, DepthImageStream depthStream, int depthFrame32Length)
{
    int tooNearDepth = depthStream.TooNearDepth;
    int tooFarDepth = depthStream.TooFarDepth;
    int unknownDepth = depthStream.UnknownDepth;
    byte[] depthFrame32 = new byte[depthFrame32Length];

    for (int i16 = 0, i32 = 0; i16 < depthFrame.Length && i32 < depthFrame32.Length; i16++, i32 += 4)
    {
        int player = depthFrame[i16] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
        int realDepth = depthFrame[i16] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;

        // transform 13-bit depth information into an 8-bit intensity appropriate
        // for display (we disregard information in most significant bit)
        byte intensity = (byte)(~(realDepth >> 4));

        if (player == 0 && realDepth == 0)
        {
            // white 
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = 255;
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = 255;
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = 255;
        }
        else if (player == 0 && realDepth == tooFarDepth)
        {
            // dark purple
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = 66;
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = 0;
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = 66;
        }
        else if (player == 0 && realDepth == unknownDepth)
        {
            // dark brown
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = 66;
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = 66;
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = 33;
        }
        else
        {
            // tint the intensity by dividing by per-player values
            depthFrame32[i32 + RedIndex] = (byte)(intensity >> IntensityShiftByPlayerR[player]);
            depthFrame32[i32 + GreenIndex] = (byte)(intensity >> IntensityShiftByPlayerG[player]);
            depthFrame32[i32 + BlueIndex] = (byte)(intensity >> IntensityShiftByPlayerB[player]);
        }
    }

    return depthFrame32;
}
```

but I'm not have any Idea how to show an Object inside the Depth View of body
I would appropriate that if someone help me. thanks

Comment: Good premise and code attempt but what research have you tried thus far?  Any other Googling?

Comment: I really tried to find something like that but unfortunately I couldn't. If anybody has a sample of that please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote HLSL code for transparency and then I will transparent one image inside the body and another image used for my foreground :

http://pastebin.com/4LNZpda8